# What's the command behind the Plasma shortcut to hide window title bar?

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, panel, 23.04, kwin

I know we can hide the title bar with a Kwin shortcut in Plasma (Meta-Alt-B) — but what about a button on the panel?

What is the command behind that shortcut?

I want to associate that command with a desktop "link to application" and then drag&drop it to the panel, so that I can hide the title bar with a panel button.